# How to shade outer of the curve androidplot

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

My goal is to fill shade the outer parabola when its downward but when i used paint that's the output.

```js
My Code

 Paint lineFill = new Paint();
        lineFill.setAlpha(200);
        lineFill.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        series1Format.setFillPaint(lineFill);
```

[image: Here's the picture]

Comment: By "outer parabola" are you talking about the blue line?

Comment: Yes. reverse that shading

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate a little more or provide a visual example of what you are trying to accomplish - it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.